# Why my code doesn't work on reversing a circularly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, reverse

I'm trying to write a function that would reverse the order of a circularly linked list (1 sentinel, double links).  Below is my code.  The original list is 15, 14, 11, 12.  I would expect the new list to be 12, 11, 14, and 15.  But I keep getting 15, 14, 11, and 12.  Can someone look at my code and give me some hints?  Thank you!

```
 void reverseCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{

    assert(q != 0);
    assert(!isEmptyCirListDeque(q));


    struct DLink *start = q->Sentinel->next;
    struct DLink *next;
    struct DLink *prev = NULL;

    while (start != NULL)
    {
        //Swap the next and previous link
        next = start->next;
        start->next = prev;
        prev = start;
        start = next;
     }     

}
```

Comment: I think you need to go through the code very slowly and make sure that each line makes sense. Maybe print out the code and write a short explanation of each line. You're right that the whole program is to much for us to help with, but a single function is too little. It may help to write a few simpler programs, perhaps singly-linked lists, until you have a stronger understanding of pointers and structures.

Comment: Where exactly in this code does `q->Sentinal->next` establish its foothold on the head of the newly reversed list?

Answer (score 1):

```
next = start->next;
start->next = prev;
start->prev = next;//This line is missing
prev = start;
start = next;
```

It would have mistaken access(or update) to the variable, logic so seems to no problem.